# Adding Folder Permissions Using Powershell

Tags: permissions, powershell, file-permissions, ntfs

I'm running this script in PowerShell:

```
Add-NTFSAccess -Path 'C:\MyFolder' -Account PROGRAMMING\IIS_IUSRS -AccessRights FullControl
```

and I'm getting this error:

*Add-NTFSAccess : Cannot bind parameter 'Account'. Cannot convert value "PROGRAMMING\IIS_IUSRS" to type
"Security2.IdentityReference2". Error: "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
At line:1 char:46
+ Add-NTFSAccess -Path 'C:\MyFolder' -Account PROGRAMMING\IIS_IUSRS -AccessRig ...
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-NTFSAccess], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,NTFSSecurity.AddAccess*

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use:

```
Add-NTFSAccess -Path 'C:\MyFolder' -Account BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS -AccessRights FullControl
```

or just

```
Add-NTFSAccess -Path 'C:\MyFolder' -Account IIS_IUSRS -AccessRights FullControl
```

`IIS_IUSRS` is a special internal group that you shouldn't/can't prefix with the computer or domain name.

For other internal groups you have to use the prefix `NT AUTHORITY` or the equivalent in your language, like:

```
Add-NTFSAccess -Path 'C:\MyFolder' -Account "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" -AccessRights FullControl
Add-NTFSAccess -Path 'C:\MyFolder' -Account "NT AUTHORITY\iusr" -AccessRights FullControl
```

Please note that `Add-NTFSAccess` is not a Windows cmdlets, it's some script that the original poster picked up somewhere but the account names described here should work elsewhere as well.

Comment: Works perfectly, ty.

Comment: However, it doesn't seem to work for other internal accounts such as "network service" or "IUSR".  What is the correct syntax for such accounts? I see nothing in Get-Help.

Comment: @AYS - I added an example for those accounts

Comment: Thank you @PeterHahndorf for your answer! I tried the second (shorter) suggestion that uses just "IIS_IUSRS", and I continued to see the same error as the OP. What did work was using "BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS" instead. No more error! Any idea why I am unable to use the shortened version of the account?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell v1.0 and the latest NTFSSecurity (3.2.3)... I know it is impossible to guess as you do not know my setup, but just asking out of curiosity :)